# Why does my for loop for cross validations keep returning the same predict values on the test data?

Tags: r, for-loop, testing, regression, predict

I want to see which number of cross validations returns the lowest MSE on the test data using OLS. I created a for loop to test a set of cross validations. The predictions on the test set of each model with a different number of cross validations (5, 6, 7...) is stored in a matrix. However, the loop continues to return the same set of predictions for each iteration. I am expecting each set of predictions to be slightly different. Even when done manually, predict continues to return the same set of predicted values for different numbers of cross validations. What am I missing? Any information would be greatly appreciated.

```
set.seed(30122020)
idtrain <- sample(c(1:dim(data_clean)[1]), round(0.8*dim(data_clean)[1]))

train <- data_clean[idtrain,]
test <- data_clean[-idtrain,]
cv_min <- 5
cv_max <- 10
cv_predict <- matrix(, nrow(test), ncol = (cv_max - cv_min + 1))
for (i in cv_min : cv_max) {
  train.control <- trainControl(method = 'cv', number = i)
  OLS.log.cv <- train(logSalePrice ~ ., data = train,
                      method = 'lm', trControl = train.control)
  
  cv_predict[, (i - cv_min + 1)] <- predict(OLS.log.cv, newdata = test)
}
ols_predict
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(data_clean)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(data_clean, 20))`.

Comment: An obvious first step is to visually inspect the input data across the trials to ensure each trial data collection is unique.  And perform summary calcs on the input data where you can to inspect the results.

Comment: See also [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: The problem is that `train()` sets up a tuning parameter grid and then tries to train over those parameters.  The linear model has no tuning parameters, so it's estimating the same model over and over again.  If you want to do CV, you could do it with `vfold_cv()` from the `rsample` package or `cv.glm()` from the `boot` package (among a host of other ways, I am sure).